Axios ETIMEDOUT error for a simple http call, why?
I made test case demo that you can clone and run with a single command:
https://github.com/nemanjam/axios-timeout-error-demo
It doesn't fail every time but in maybe 70% of cases. The confusing thing is that code does nothing special, it just does simple fetch of html page by url.
I assume http server is doing something unusual that causes Axios client to trigger timeout error. Same will happen with any other http client, like fetch.
I tried to set some axios config to prevent error but without success, timeout exception is still triggered.
// src/axios-instance.ts

export const axiosConfig = {
  timeout,
  // important to terminate connection and prevent timeout exception
  httpsAgent: new Agent({
    keepAlive: true,
    timeout,
    scheduling: 'fifo',
  }),
};

/** Must use singleton. */
export default class MyAxiosInstance {
  private static instance: AxiosInstance;

  public static getInstance(): AxiosInstance {
    if (!MyAxiosInstance.instance)
      MyAxiosInstance.instance = axios.create(axiosConfig);

    return MyAxiosInstance.instance;
  }
}

Can some of you make it perform reliable, successful page fetch every time without triggering any exceptions and provide logical explanation what is going on?

servers often time rate limit requests so you have to time them.
on the axios documentation page it goes over it with an example.
const {data} = await axios.post(LOCAL_SERVER_URL, myBuffer, {
  onUploadProgress: ({progress, rate}) => {
    console.log(`Upload [${(progress*100).toFixed(2)}%]: ${(rate / 1024).toFixed(2)}KB/s`)
  },
   
  maxRate: [100 * 1024], // 100KB/s limit
});

